# Do Dementors have the ability to breed?

Tags: harry-potter

If they're immortal beings wouldn't their population keep increasing and increasing if they could procreate?

Comment: Can't be bothered to find the quotes for an answer but to hold you over: they can breed, and the dense fog is a byproduct of their breeding (as explained in the books, but not films). I'm sure Richard, DVK or Slytherincess will have a quote before long :)

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock - That's a better dupe than mine

Comment: Huh. Guess I better go read the books again. At least it WAS Slytherincess with the links.

Comment: I question the correctness of those answers, considering the word "breeding" IS used in the books. And, as much as I love JKR and her books, I'd honestly consider a quote from one of her characters to be more reliable than a quote from her.

Comment: I thought it was a bit different but okay

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - I think it's better served to discuss the validity of the original correct answers at the original answer, not in the comments of the duplicate question. As one who gave one of the correct answers, I know I would be more comfortable with that. Or chat -- I'm frequently in chat.

Comment: Technically Dementors are amortal, not immortal. That is to say, they are not alive or dead, and thus cannot die.